# MAC OSX: How to unzip password protected .zip file

Tags: mac, passwords, zip

I need to unzip a .zip file which is password protected.

I am able to unzip the .zip file using a windows PC with 7zip.

I tried several tools Keka, iZIP, unarchiver ... and got always an answer like this "...wrong password". But I proofed the password with the windows PC.

So I tried it with commandline, in this way:

```
unzip -P password my.zip -d my_folder
```

But I see the following error:

```
...unsupported compression method 99
```

So how can I unzip this file under MAC OS X?

Comment: Not a real solution, but if you can unzip it on a PC, why not just unzip it there, then put it in a different archive with no password for your Mac?

Comment: What was used to to create the zip file in the first place?

Comment: Is there something special about the password - non-standard character set etc? I unzip password-protected zip files all the time, using nothing more than the built-in Unarchiver.

Comment: Because I will get these archive via e-mail being on road and I only have a windows PC desktop in the office

Comment: No password is plain forward, nothing special. Only standard charakters.

Comment: I do not have configuration used for building the archive. I only know it was made by 7zip.

Answer (score 20):

```
unsupported compression method 99
```

Means the compression algorithm (99 which is AES encryption) isn't supported.

For OSX the only program supporting this I know of it [p7zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) (Available with brew and other package managers too).

Comment: No I installed p7zip with Homebrew, did not work. But with new error, "wrong password". But it is the right password, I used c&p.

Comment: Be careful you didn't copy/paste any whitespaces (space, newline etc). If you're sure of that try a `7z l -slt file.zip`

Comment: @Thorsten Also, are there any non-US-ASCII characters (non-English, accented, etc)? If so, you might be running into encoding issues.

Comment: @Mikael, I tried your suggestion, it is quit interesting
`7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs x64)
...
Path = xxx.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 56311
Path = 2017-105 3_0xxx.docx
Folder = -
...
Attributes = A
Encrypted = +
Comment = 
CRC = 5C27931F
Method = AES-256 Deflate
Host OS = FAT
Version = 20
Volume Index = 0` So for me the archive looks good.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, yes there is a blank in the password. Is it possible to masquerade it? Perhaps this is problem.

Comment: @Thorsten you need to escape or quote spaces. These 2 commands will work:
`7z -p{"pass word"} x pass_word.zip` or
`7z -p{pass\ word} x pass_word.zip` - 
The first will quote the password and the second will escape the space. In this case do the same thing.

Comment: My password had "!" in it. For me, neither of these worked: `7z -p{"password!"} x file.zip` nor `7z -p{password\!} x file.zip`. But running it *without* `-p` and entering the password interactively worked well.

Comment: I also had the issue with the exclamation mark; using `-p'password!'` worked for me. The double quotes do not hide the special meaning of the exclamation mark from `bash`, whilst the single quote means that `bash` will not do anything with what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

Keka for Mac os really works perfect with zip protected files (error 1 type or unsupporter compression method 99 in Terminal) > Keka prompt for password then you must fill in something with any letters (eg DEMO), then it does some work, then it tells you it failed...

BUT it did NOT : check it out, your unzipped map is just right there besides your zip file. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used 7-Zip 21.02 alpha (2021-05-06) for Mac console (7z2102-mac.tar.xz), downloaded from the 7-zip.org download page, and it worked just fine with AES password protected zip files on Mac with Catalina. Do a `-h` instead of guessing how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

If you (like me) are trying to unzip `ipa` file and gets the similar error.

`skipping: Payload/App.app/some-file.nib  unsupported compression method 99`

Check this project https://github.com/sskaje/unzip-lzfse it's worked for me.

It's all about Apple's LZFSE compression:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZFSE

https://github.com/lzfse/lzfse

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue with a zipped pdf file (pwd protected) from a utilities provider. Tried unsuccessfully with Terminal via command line. 
In the end I downloaded Keka for Mac, and when I tried to unzip the file using Keka it prompted me for the password, and opened the file! 
Hope this saves someone else some time.